# Corba Client - Python & Corba Server - Java

Tags: java, python-2.7, client-server, corba

We need to interact with Corba Server which is implemented in Java, from Python (Corba Client). Corba Server is already an existing one, we don’t want any change to be done in that. 
Can anyone help us in , how to interact with Java Code from Python Code  . Any information/ suggestion / idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to implement your client using a CORBA Python implementation like [omniORB](http://omniorb.sourceforge.net/). At the moment you use an ORB that supports Python it will interoperate with Java (at least when both implementations are mature and bug free).

Comment: So, should I have to compile the idl file with java Idl compiler (Jacorb) and python Idl compiler (OmniORBpy) and do the server implementation in Java and Client implementation in Python.. Will this work??

Comment: Yes, that will work. The IDL defines the interface between client and server, compile the IDL with the programming language of your choice. omniORB has support for Python, R2CORBA has for Ruby, TAOX11 for C++11.